# How to equally partitioning an array into predefined size and loop folding in Python

Tags: python

I'm using python and try to do 10 folds looping. To explain this problem, I've an array of any size > 10 of any content, for example:

```
myArray = [12,14,15,22,16,20,30,25,21,5,3,8,11,19,40,33,23,45,65]
smallArray = []
bigArray = []
```

**I want to do two things:**

1. divide "myArray" into 10 equal parts [e.g. part1, part2, ..., part10]
2. I need to loop 10 times and each time **to do the following:**

   - smallArray = one distinct part a time
   - the remaining parts are assigned into "bigArray"

and keep doing this for the remaining 10 folds.

the output for example:

```
Loop1: smallArray = [part1], bigArray[the remaining parts except part1]
Loop2: smallArray = [part2], bigArray[the remaining parts except part2]
...
Loop10: smallArray = [part10], bigArray[the remaining parts except part10]
```

How to do so in Python?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this that is different from iterating over the array?

Comment: Is `len(myArray)` a multiple of 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
l = len(myArray)

#create start and end indices for each slice
slices = ((i * l // 10, (i + 1) * l // 10) for i in xrange(0, 10))

#build (small, big) pairs
pairs = [(myArray[a:b], myArray[:a] + myArray[b:]) for a, b in slices]

for small, big in pairs:
    pass
```

Comment: `len(pairs)==9`, but I think that's more an issue with OP being unclear.

Comment: @kojiro: fixed. I forgot `xrange` excluded the upper bound